# How to show answers based on the certain question Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm writing a site where users can ask questions. I don't understand what problem is in my code, but when I'm trying to show all answers on certain question - nothing appears on the screen. I tried to use everything: QuerySet with filter, get, using id, but nothing works. Seems like problem in two thing: Django doesn't understand what answers to show or my template is incorrect. Here is the code:

models.py

```
class Question(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True,         verbose_name="URL")
    detail = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})


class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    detail = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.detail
```

urls.py

```
    urlpatterns = [
    path('', QuestionView.as_view(), name='forum'),
    path('search/', SearchView.as_view(), name='search'),
    path('question/<slug:slug>/', QuestionDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('answer/', AnswerView.as_view(), name='answer')
    ]
```

views.py

```
class QuestionView(ListView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'forum/forum.html'
    context_object_name = 'questions'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 1

class QuestionDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'forum/detail.html'

class AnswerView(ListView):
    model = Answer
    template_name = 'forum/detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'answers'


    def get_queryset(self):
        quest = Question.objects.get(id=1)
        return Answer.objects.filter(question=quest)
```

templates/detail.html

```
{% for answer in answers %}
    <div class="col-11">
        <p>{{ answer.detail }}</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="mr-3">BigBossData</a><span>5 комментариев</span></p>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should use a [forward relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add).

```
quest = Question.objects.get(pk=1)
answers = quest.answer_set.all()
```

Comment: I tried to use a forward relation, but it doesn't work as well. I added to AnswerView get_queryset function and wrote this code: quest =     Question.objects.get(pk=1)
        answers = quest.answer_set.all()
        return answers

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> def get_queryset(self):
>     quest = Question.objects.get(id=1)
>     return Answer.objects.filter(question=quest)
> ```

Instead of using id=1, use pk=1

Btw since it always gets the first question with pk=1, the template will only and always show answers of question 1.
Since you said "I'm trying to show all answers on **certain question**". So for this you need some changes.

```
URL:
    urlpatterns = [
    path('', QuestionView.as_view(), name='forum'),
    path('search/', SearchView.as_view(), name='search'),
    path('question/<slug:slug>/', QuestionDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    **path('answer/<slug:slug>/', AnswerView.as_view(), name='answer')**
    ]
```

views:

```
 class AnswerView(ListView):
     model = Answer
     template_name = 'forum/detail.html'
     context_object_name = 'answers'


    def get_queryset(self):
        **question_slug = self.kwargs['slug']
        quest = Question.objects.get(slug=question_slug) # this will give you the question object, whose answers you want to show
        return Answer.objects.filter(question=quest) # this will return all answers for the above question.**
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I did what you said, nothing changed. It doesn't work. Maybe the problem is in template or models relation?

Comment: Inside function get_queryset(self), add this line -> print(Answer.objects.filter(question=quest)), before returning. 
 
In this way you can see what it prints. If it prints the answers, that means there is a problem in template. Otherwise the problem is in view.

Comment: Nothing works. I did evrything like Django documentation tells, have no idea what's wrong. I noticed, when I remove the cycle in templates it shows what I wrote in span and BIgBossData, otherwise, when I'm using for - nothing appears

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that problem by adding
`{% for answer in object.answer_set.all %}`
Also I delete get_queryset()